# Have multiple conditions trigger the same color

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm using Google Sheets, a beginner to this (just started yesterday) and trying to create a condition where:

`if text contains "x, y, or z"`

`then color red`

There must be some way to do it because I've been doing separate conditions for each one and it's taking up time to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Select the relevant range (I am assuming starts at A1) and clear any existing CF rules from it. Format, Conditional formatting..., Format cells if... `Custom formula is` and

```
=regexmatch(A1,"x|y|z")
```

with red fill and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Looks a little bit ugly, but this is the way you can do it:

```
=OR(INDIRECT( ADDRESS( ROW( ) ; COLUMN( ) ) )= "x";
    INDIRECT( ADDRESS( ROW( ) ; COLUMN( ) ) )= "y";
    INDIRECT( ADDRESS( ROW( ) ; COLUMN( ) ) )= "z")
```

In my opinion there is no better way to get the current cell as with the long term.