# How to write IF AND regular expression match

Tags: regex, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to write a simple formula for Google Sheets. The logic is as follows:

`if(it is a specific date & it is today){fill cell color with this color}`

I know this needs to be done in the conditional formatting section but I am unable to get it right.

I've tried:

`if(TODAY(),RegExMatch("Tuesday May 2, 2017"))`

`RegExMatch("Tuesday May 2, 2017") AND IF(TODAY())`

`IF(TODAY() AND RegExMatch("Tuesday May 2, 2017"))`

but none of those work and return errors such as 'parse & invalid' when attempting to write it in the cell box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REGEXMATCH can be used in Conditional formatting ([eg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43576823/1505120)) but it seems way overkill here. Please select the relevant range (I am assuming ColumnA - populated with 'true' dates, not text) and clear any existing CF rules from it. Format, Conditional formatting..., Format cells if... `Custom formula is` and

```
=and(A1=today(),A1=42858)
```

with fill colour of choice and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

Here `42858` happens to be the index number for today, but would be replaced with that for your specific date.

Comment: hmm alright, this seems like it would work but I don't know how to find the index number for a specific cell...could you tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you tried just getting the value of TODAY()? It returns the date in `mm/dd/yyyy` format. Your RegExMatch will always fail.
2. You don't need to use any formula. Use [this guide](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) to see how you can use conditional formatting rules on individual or multiple cells. The correct way to do what you want to do is to select a cell, click on Format -> Conditional formatting... -> Format cells if... -> Date is -> today
3. If you're referring to the cell box in the 'Custom formula' section, you simply need to write `=TODAY()`.

Comment: I realize now I wasn't very clear in my question: I would need a custom formula because I am changing the color of the cell if it is a specific date and that cell is equal to today's date. I could absolutely go to each individual cell and have a conditional formatting record for each cell but I'd rather do this in one formula.

Comment: Then I think my 3rd point answers your question? You can select multiple cells and apply the custom formula `=TODAY()` to all of them in one go.

Comment: using only `today` accounts for only half of the condition. The other half being `it is a specific date`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I'm following exactly, but if your date is in col A:

`=AND(DATEVALUE(a1)=datevalue("5/2/2017"),DATEVALUE(a1)=DATEVALUE(today()))`

this seems to work.  The date has to be parseable to date by sheets for DATEVALUE to work though.

[image]

Image has the column in an IF as well setting 1 or 0 just an example of the logic too.